# Installing Linux on Wyse Cx0: minimal system needed

Tags: distro-recommendation, rdesktop

I got my hands on a couple of wyse thin clients [Link to Thinclient(Wyse Cx0)](http://www.nationwidesurplus.com/p-30084-wyse-cx0-c00x-128f512r-xenith-902196-01l-ps2-keyboard-mouse-power-legs-set.aspx)

I want to use them for RDP purpose. The original plan was to install Tinycore on them and to use Rdesktop to rdp to the server, but the latest rdesktop (1.7) on Tinycore does not support windows server 2008 R2 (had some issues with my pointer device not showing on screen).

Now what I am looking for is a Linux distribution that uses under 128MB of flash memory and under 512MB of RAM. The OS must be capable of running rdesktop 1.8.3.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the internal flash memory. You can change it up to 8GB than get ddr2 RAM from a laptop and replace it to have a 1GHz 2GB ram and 8 GB internal storage. Then you can run up to Win 8 32-bit if you like. I dual boot mine with Ubuntu 18.04 and Win 7 black edition.